# Volume of revolution about $x=3$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

Find the volume generated by revolving the region shown below about $x=3$ using Washer method.

[image]

We have outer radius as a function of $y$ as:
$$R(y)=3$$
Inner radius as a function of $y$ as:
$$r(y)=3-\sqrt{y}$$
So the required volume is:
$$\int_{0}^{9}\pi (9-(3-\sqrt{y})^2)dy=\frac{135\pi}{2}$$
But the answer is $\frac{572\pi}{2}$.
Where i went wrong?

Comment: Your working seems correct. The official answer cannot be correct. Even if we took the whole cylinder the volume will be $\pi \cdot 3^2 \cdot 9 = 81 \pi$ much lower than the official answer. Also as the numerator is even, not sure why they are writing it in fraction when the division is by $2$.